# How do deposit bitcoin works?

Tags: blockchain, api, faucets

I visit so many faucets everyday and some gaming faucets like wonderlandcoin,playbitcoin,faucetbirds,robotcoingame and many more.I also visit some betting websites like satoshibet,777dice and many others.

Some of them have a deposit bitcoin option to progress in game faster.

The website automatically generates a unique deposit address for me.
I am also planning to build a betting game website so I wanted to know that how to make that deposit address part for my website.
I actually don't know, how it works.
It may be a script or a address generated by some API.
HELP ME. PLEASE
EDIT

I also want to know that how those websites triggers that the payment is sent by a particular user?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a key pair with bitcoin-cli. Then you can display the public key as an address for users to deposit to. Specifically, use the commands getnewaddress and dumpprivkey. If you set up a unique key pair for each user, then you can easily see how much each user has deposited.

Here are some examples:
https://bitcoin.org/en/developer-examples#simple-spending

Comment: Please read the edit

Comment: The website knows which user paid, because they know to which user they gave the address.